# What are the popular technologies for creating, modifying and testing DROOLS and jBPM?

Tags: workflow, drools, jbpm, drools-flow, business-process-management

I am new to the technology fold and am looking for stable technologies for enabling users to create, modify and test Rules (especially DROOLS) and workflows (especially jBPM). Are these more like wizards or graphical tools?

Comment: Does user3301684 know about Drools Guvnor? Other than this, it's not a good question, invites opinions, too "open"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It just depends on which platform you want to use. Usually each rules platform includes its own tooling/BRMS. For instance, Drools has Guvnor/Workbench and some Eclipse plugins.

I haven't used them for a while, but a few years ago, IBM ILOG JRules and FICO Blaze Advisor both had (Eclipse-based I think) IDEs for building rules management web sites. i.e. Developers would use the IDE to generate a web site. The web site would be deployed and used by business users to manage their rules. I'm pretty sure that the Pega platform follows a similar pattern.

All of the above provide a means of defining a business model, a guided editor GUI for building complex rules and a GUI for decision tables. They usually also provide some form of add-on tooling for business process workflow.

Other than that, I use JUnit for testing. But that's just my preference.

Comment: IBM's ODM product (formally known as JRules) has a component called DVS (Decision Validation Service) that allows the business users to test rules from Decision Centre (web based rule authoring application). They can run standard "unit" tests by providing inputs and expected outputs, and DVS will report back which scenarios have passed or failed. Then there are simulations, which you can see the effect of rule changes against pre-defined KPI's (Key Performance Indicators). For example, how many customers are accepted/declined if I change the rules. KPI's do require up front dev however.